# Finding (source/original) Shlokas in the RigVeda

Tags: rig-veda, shloka, science

[This](http://www.religiousforums.com/threads/scientific-miracles-in-hindu-scriptures-must-see.84199/) website provides the following translation of the Shlokas from the RigVeda:

> "He made this Earth fixed by different devices like hills and
>   mountains in shape of pegs but it still rotates . Sun never sets; all
>   parts of earth are not in Darkness."
>
> "There are suns in all directions, the night sky being full of them."
>
> "There are planets in all directions, but only visible in night sky."

Although, neither does it provide the Shlokas or the references to them. I was wondering if anyone who has gone through the RigVeda can provide me with the original Shlokas.

Answer (score 4):

This is partial answer.

First mantra is [Rigveda 2.12.2](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02012.htm).

> यः पर्थिवीं वयथमानामद्रंहद यः पर्वतान परकुपितानरम्णात | 
>  यो
> अन्तरिक्षं विममे वरीयो यो दयामस्तभ्नात स जनास इन्द्रः ||
>
> yaḥ pṛthivīṃ vyathamānāmadṛṃhad yaḥ parvatān prakupitānaramṇāt |  yo
> antarikṣaṃ vimame varīyo yo dyāmastabhnāt sa janāsa indraḥ ||

[Griffith's](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02012.htm) translation

> He who fixed fast and firm the earth that staggered, and set at rest the agitated mountains, Who measured out the air's wide middle region
> and gave the heaven support, He, men, is Indra.

Translation from [Indiascriptures](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/vedas/rig-veda/mandala-ii/topic-12),

> He, who fixed firm the moving earth; who tranquillized the incensed mountains; who spread the spacious firmament; who consolidated the
> heaven; he, men, is Indra. Who Tranquillized the Incensed Mountains-
>
> Yah parvatan prakupitan aramnat; the Scholiast says he quieted the
> mountains, going hither and thither, as long as they had wings: Indra
> cut them off.

Regarding second mantra, all blogs and books (from google) say "Sarva Dishanaam, Suryaha, Suryaha, Suryaha" is source of Mantra which i couldn't find in Rigveda.